# Configurar jquery, bootstrap de forma global desde el Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con ASP.NET MVC5 intento configurar jquery y bootstrap desde el Layout, pero no me esta funcionando.

**Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <title>@ViewBag.Title XXXXXX</title>
<meta name="description" content="Modern effects and styles for off-canvas navigation with CSS transitions and SVG animations using Snap.svg" />
<meta name="keywords" content="sidebar, off-canvas, menu, navigation, effect, inspiration, css transition, SVG, morphing, animation" />
<meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico">


<link href="~/Content/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/css/menu_sideslide.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

<style>
    .menu li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu a + ul {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu li:hover > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #434343;
    }

    .menu a + ul > li {
        display: block;
        min-width: 140px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="Site container" style="width:100%; height:100%; background: #ffffff;">
        <div class="menu-wrap">
            <nav class="menu">
                <div class="icon-list" style="text-decoration-style:none;">
                    <ul class="main-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i><span>Mantenimiento</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/Proceso/index">Proceso</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Chinos &amp; Trousers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>Alerts</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Messages</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i><span>Comments</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Analytics</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>Reading List</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
        <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Menu</button>
    </div>
    <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Open Menu</button>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="content">
            <header class="codrops-header"></header>
            <div class="container body-content" style="background: #ffffff;">
                @RenderBody()
                <hr />
                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/main.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

**Vista** donde pretendo usar jquery y bootstrap

```
   @model IEnumerable<Votacion.Web.Models.ProcesoViewModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Proceso</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Materialize/materialize/css/materialize.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="~/Materialize/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    @*<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@

    <link href="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="fixed-action-btn">
            <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
                <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i> 
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="procesos" class="table table-hover display">
                <thead style="background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; color: #fff;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>ProcesoId</td>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var row in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@row.ProcesoId</td>
                            <td>@row.Nombre</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#procesos").DataTable({
            "language": {
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "sUrl": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            }
        });
    });



    //$(document).ready(function() {
    //    $('#clientes').DataTable();
    //});

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#procesos').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "searching":false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "Proceso/Index",
                "dataType": "jsonp"
            }
        });
    });



    function llamarVistaParcial() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreatePV", "Cliente")',
            data: {},
            success: function(response) {
                //$('#resultado').html('');
                $('#resultado').empty().html(response);
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            }
        });
        //$("#myModal").modal('show');
    };
    </script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
            var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No se si tenga que ver algo en esto `BundleConfig`

```
   using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Votacion.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // Para obtener más información sobre Bundles, visite http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Utilice la versión de desarrollo de Modernizr para desarrollar y obtener información. De este modo, estará
            // preparado para la producción y podrá utilizar la herramienta de compilación disponible en http://modernizr.com para seleccionar solo las pruebas que necesite.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal ó que me falta configurar?

No esta tomando jquery
[image: jquery]

Saludos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coincido con lo que menciona el buen @Rafael Acosta, eliminar esa directiva del `layout null` es necesario, por otro lado, también es innecesario volver a definir el HTML, el Header y el Body. Ahora bien, en la vista donde quieres colocar el datatable:

```
@model IEnumerable<Votacion.Web.Models.ProcesoViewModel>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Materialize/materialize/css/materialize.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" />        
<script src="~/Materialize/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>   
<link href="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="fixed-action-btn">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
            <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i> 
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
            <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
            <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
            <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table id="procesos" class="table table-hover display">
            <thead style="background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; color: #fff;">
                <tr>
                    <td>ProcesoId</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var row in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@row.ProcesoId</td>
                        <td>@row.Nombre</td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@*Presta atención aquí*@
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#procesos").DataTable({
            "language": {
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "sUrl": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            }
        });
    });



    //$(document).ready(function() {
    //    $('#clientes').DataTable();
    //});

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#procesos').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "searching":false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "Proceso/Index",
                "dataType": "jsonp"
            }
        });
    });



    function llamarVistaParcial() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreatePV", "Cliente")',
            data: {},
            success: function(response) {
                //$('#resultado').html('');
                $('#resultado').empty().html(response);
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            }
        });
        //$("#myModal").modal('show');
    };
    </script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
            var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems);
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Explicación**

En tu layout tienes al final la siguiente línea:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Esto indica que en esa sección/zona/área/ubicación vas a colocar fragmentos de código de tal modo que se mantenga el orden necesario.

Lectura recomendada: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view

Answer (score 3):

En la Vista donde quieres usar **jquery** y **bootstrap**, estás indicando que **NO** cargue el `Layout`:

```
@{
   Layout = null;
 }
```

**Elimina** esta directiva, y te cargará el `Layout` junto con los archivos jquery y bootstrap.

Comment: Hola, ya lo elimine, no me esta aplicando jquery ni bootstrap

Comment: Has inspeccionado el código fuente de la página, para ver si te está renderizando correctamente los <script /> de jQuery y Bootstrap?. Tienes correctamente instalado en las carpetas correspondientes jQuery y Bootstrap desde NuGet?

Comment: Que tienes en el archivo `_ViewStart.cshtml`?

Comment: Hola si esta bien instalado desde nuguet, voy a poner una imagen del error en el hijo inicial.

Comment: @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: Sigue saliendo el mismo error