# Problema con @Render Bundle MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

De antemano agradezco que tomen tiempo para ayudarme.

Estoy montando un plantilla de Bootstrap en un proyecto MVC, he montado gran parte.

El problema viene con unos scripts que no están renderizando correctamente y no ejecuta ciertas funcionalidades en el sitio, por ejempl*o, al dar clic en el botón de barras, ejecuta un evento que oculta el nav o lo muestra*, simplemente no ejecuta el evento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi **BundleConfig.cs** es el siguiente:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // Render CSS (OK).
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css").Include(
                  "~/css/styles.css"));

        // Render SCRIPTS (Fail)
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
            "~/js/Alert.js", //(Solo tiene una alerta("ok"), renderiza correctamente y muestra la alerta).
            "~/js/scripts.js")); //(Tiene funcionalidades para ocultar/mostrar nav, no renderiza y no ejecuta el evento).
    
        // Render ICONS (Ok)
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Icons").Include(
                  "~/Icons/all.min.js"));

        // Render DATATABLE (Ok)
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/DataTable").Include(
                  "~/DataTable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.cs"));

    }
```

En mi **HTML** tengo:

```
<head>
 <!--Resto de codigo...-->

@Styles.Render("~/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/Icons")
@Scripts.Render("~/DataTable")
</head>

<body>
 <!--Resto de codigo...-->

@Scripts.Render("~/js")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

El script tendría que ejecutar el evento del nav y dar como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(**Pude ejecutar el evento añadiendo `<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>` directamente a mi index de manera convencional.**)

En consola me muestra el siguiente error, no se ha definido el script:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguido, me envía a cierta linea del script.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían asesorarme? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar información adicional como la pestaña de la consola de esa pantalla, por favor?

Comment: Me manda un error, dice lo siguiente:  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    <anonymous> https://localhost:44327/js/scripts.js:22
scripts.js:22:1
    <anonymous> https://localhost:44327/js/scripts.js:22

Comment: en la pregunta incluye esos detalles por favor :) Revisa esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336003/822

Comment: Gracias, de momento he añadido información adicional, seguido, revisare el link que me das.

Comment: ¿dónde llamas a jquery?

Comment: Saludos. Conforme a lo que colocas usas el **jQuery** y **Bootstrap**; ambos incluyen sus correspondientes archivos **css** y **js**; te sugiero en `RegisterBundles` te asegures sean los primeros (en el orden antes mencionado) estén incluidos; seguido de ello lo demás que agregues y/o creaste para tu sitio. Basicamente indica que para el momento que se ejecuta donde menciona el fallo no existe (aún) cargado el jQuery (o no se esta cargando o no lo estas cargando actualmente).

Comment: Pude solucionarlo, gracias por el tiempo dedicado, me ayudaron sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

pude solucionar el problema.

Nunca mande a llamar correctamente mi JQuery, lo hacía desde:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></scrip>
```

Mientras el script.js lo hacia desde:

```
   // Render SCRIPTS ()
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
            "~/js/scripts.js",
            ));
```

Usando @Scripts.Render

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js")
```

Al final quedó de esta manera:

```
      // Render SCRIPTS (Fail)
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
            "~/js/scripts.js",
            "~/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
            ));
```